# "Unknown Display" for previously-known monitor after installing HydraPaper and GNOME Tweak [16.04]

Tags: 16.04, multiple-monitors, display, display-resolution

Previously my two external monitors (connected with DVI) were working fine---my computer detected the proper resolution and preserved my display arrangement every time I connected them fresh. I recently installed GNOME Tweak and HydraPaper to mess around with wallpapers. Since doing this, (i) my display arrangement is no longer preserved, and (ii) one of my two monitors shows up as an "Unknown Display", with the proper resolution unavailable.

Uninstalling HydraPaper and Tweak, restarting, and unplugging monitors doesn't help. I'm not sure if HydraPaper or Tweak even caused the problem, but they're the only changes I can think of. I have a Dell laptop with recently-updated BIOS, so it shouldn't be a firmware issue?

I'd prefer a solution that doesn't rely on doing `xrandr --addmode` manually, like [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/860735/unknown-display-in-ubuntu-16-04), and instead get my system to re-recognize the display automatically as it once did.

Comment: Update: tried adding the native monitor resolution using `xrandr` for the "Unknown Display", when I apply these changes the screen goes black, as if it can't support this resolution now..??

Comment: Update 2: in desperation I re-installed Ubuntu and the problem is still there, which points to the problem being in the monitor itself